# Filtering dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

i'm working with dictionaries in python, but can't seem to find a solution.

My dictionary looks like this:

```
res = result['result']._asdict()
res.keys()                                                                                    
['EGOVMON.CRE.1.2', 'EGOVMON.PDF.03', 'EGOVMON.PDF.05', 'WCAG.PDF.14', 'EGOVMON.TITLE.1.2']
```

First of all, I want to filter the keys. I only want the keys who starts with 'EGOVMON.PDF' and 'WCAG.PDF'. This is what I have done so far:

```
filterkeys=[v for k,v in res.items() if k.startswith('EGOVMON.PDF') or k.startswith('WCAG.PDF')]
```

print filterkeys will give me a new dictionary:

```
[[<SOAPpy.Types.structType item at 140493364567432>: {'column': 1, 'line': 0, 'type':           'assertion', 'mode': 'automatic', 'result': 1.0}], [<SOAPpy.Types.structType item at 140493353171712>: {'column': 1, 'line': 0, 'type': 'assertion', 'mode': 'automatic', 'result':     0.0}]
```

Now here is where I'm stuck. I do not know how to iterate over this dictionary. My main goal is to use the key 'result' and its value.

To be more clear: How can I output the following:

```
EGOVMON.PDF.03  result: 1.0
WCAG.PDF.14     result: 0.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just turn your filter set back into a dictionary: filtered_res = dict([(k,v) for k,v in res.items() if ...]), then work with that dictionary as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

With the instruction

```
filterkeys=[v for k,v in res.items() if k.startswith('EGOVMON.PDF') or k.startswith('WCAG.PDF')]
```

you are producing a list of values, not a list of keys. It should read...

```
filterkeys=[k for k,v in res.items() if k.startswith('EGOVMON.PDF') or k.startswith('WCAG.PDF')]
```

And to get the value of the field 'result', read it from your `res` dictionary...

```
for k in filterkeys:
    print(k, res[k]['result'])   #with the formatting you need
```